# DataAnnotations MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations

Here is a class "Cars" and I have 2 attributs (min/max CO2):

```
    public class Cars
    {
       [Range("MinCO2", int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "MaxCO2 < MinCO2")]
       public int MaxCO2 { get; set; }
       [Range(0, "MaxCO2", ErrorMessage = "MaxCO2 > MinCO2")]
       public int MinCO2 { get; set; }
    }
```

I use the Data Annotation 'Range' to fix the minimum and the maximum value.

But I want to use the car's attribut to fix the minimum or the maximum value.

Or if there is another solution with jQuery, it can be possible.

Thank you so much.

Comment: How can jQuery possibly be used for this?

Comment: I will add the script on my view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

Send Mininum value and Maximum value from Controller to View using Model or ViewBag/ViewData

```
ViewBag.Min=0;
ViewBag.Max=Int32.MaxValue;
```

In View use jQuery validation to specify min and max validation using passed values.
View:

```
<script language="javascript">
var mi="@ViewBag.Min";
var mx="@ViewBag.Max";
$(document).ready(function()
{
$( "#myform" ).validate({
rules: {
field: {
required: true,
min: mi,
max:mx,
}
};
});
});
```

http://jqueryvalidation.org/min-method/

Answer (score 0):

Thank you malkam!

```
 $("#MinCO2").change(function () {
        var minValue = this.value;
        $("#MaxCO2").rules('add', {
            range: [minValue, Number.MAX_VALUE],
            messages: {
                range: "La valeur MaxCO2 est inférieur à la valeur MinCO2"
            }
        });
    });

    $("#MaxCO2").change(function () {
        var maxValue = this.value;
        $("#MinCO2").rules('add', {
            range: [Number.MIN_VALUE, maxValue],
            messages: {
                range: "La valeur MinCO2 est supérieur à la valeur MaxCO2"
            }
        });
    });
```